# How to stop receiver disconnecting with Chrome Sender

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast

I am testing out a Chrome based Sender application with a Custom Receiver.

I want to know how to stop the Receiver closing when I click "Stop Casting" in the Google Cast extension.

Is that possible? I understand it says "Stop Casting", but I'm just curious if it is possible to have the Receiver carry on regardless.

This is linked to the fact I need to know how to have 2 options for an Android Sender, where the user can choose "Disconnect" and "Exit App", the later being the only way to close the Custom Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can just "exit" the Sender app (close the browser, navigate to another page), meaning that you don't stop casting via the extension, nor via calling `stopApp` on the session, and it should continue casting, assuming you don't have something in your receiver app that closes it when there are no active sender sessions.

A lot of the receiver examples seem to do this, so I'd review your receiver app and make sure you're not doing that in your `onSenderDisconnected` handler.